# Debug using CLION and

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, clion

I am working with CLION (under GNU/Linux). I write applications for ARM processors and thus I cannot use the default way of debugging. Nonetheless I still want to debug my application (but not on the hardware target). I can do it with gdb and Qemu on the command line, but this is not nice for me (for usability reasons). I am looking for a way to use Qemu within CLION to exploit the IDE's functionality. I tried out several things:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10428-qemu-for-clion
or
https://www.jetbrains.com/de-de/clion/features/embedded-dev.html
but none of it seems to work for me. Can anyone please help me?

Regards

Lukas

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you may want to try remote cross debugging with gdbserver.

CLION has some support for gdbserver see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/remote-debug.html#debug-shared-libs

Comment: yeah that works on the hardware. But I want to debug on the development pc.